# How to rolling non-overlapping window in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like:

```
       c1   
    0  10  
    1  11  
    2  12
    3  13
    4  14
    5  15
    6  16
    7  17
```

I want to find the minimum for every 3 rows. which looks like:

```
       c1  min 
    0  10  10
    1  11  10
    2  12  10
    3  13  13
    4  14  13
    5  15  13
    6  16  16
    7  17  16
```

and the number of rows might not be divisible by 3. I can't achieve it with rolling function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there is default index values use integer division by `3` and pass to [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `min`:

```
df['min'] = df['c1'].groupby(df.index // 3).transform('min')
```

Or if any `index` generate helper `np.arange`:

```
df['min'] = df['c1'].groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 3).transform('min')
```

---

```
print (df)
   c1  min
0  10   10
1  11   10
2  12   10
3  13   13
4  14   13
5  15   13
6  16   16
7  17   16
```

Comment: what if I would like to do that with overlapping by 1 row for instance?

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this:

```
>>> df['min'] = df['c1'][::3]
>>> df.ffill().astype(int)

   c1  min
0  10   10
1  11   10
2  12   10
3  13   13
4  14   13
5  15   13
6  16   16
7  17   16
```